# how to use Elastislide – A Responsive jQuery Carousel Plugin in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap

i m new to wordpress and i want to use this jquery plugin in my site. i start to add this in my wordpress plugin list but it doesn't work as its not a plugin thats why i want to know thta how can i use it in my site means in which files i have to change in my theme.should i have to change my header.php file??
please help me guys.

Here is my header.php  file:

```
<?php
/** header.php
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till </header>
 *
 * @author      Konstantin Obenland
 * @package     The Bootstrap
 * @since       1.0 - 05.02.2012
 */

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
    <head>
        <?php tha_head_top(); ?>
        <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <title><?php wp_title( '&laquo;', true, 'right' ); ?></title>

        <?php tha_head_bottom(); ?>
        <?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head>

    <body <?php body_class(); ?>>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="page" class="hfeed row">
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("widgetized-page-top") ) : ?>



                    <?php endif; ?>
<div class="span8"> 

    <?php if ( the_bootstrap_options()->navbar_searchform ) {
                                            the_bootstrap_navbar_searchform();
                                        } ?> 
</div>
                <?php tha_header_before(); ?>
                <header id="branding" role="banner" class="span12">
                    <?php tha_header_top();
                    wp_nav_menu( array(
                        'container'         =>  'nav',
                        'container_class'   =>  'subnav clearfix',
                        'theme_location'    =>  'header-menu',
                        'menu_class'        =>  'nav nav-pills pull-right',
                        'depth'             =>  3,
                        'fallback_cb'       =>  false,
                        'walker'            =>  new The_Bootstrap_Nav_Walker,
                    ) ); ?>
                    <hgroup>
                        <h1 id="site-title">
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
                                <span><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></span>
                            </a>
                        </h1>
                        <h2 id="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
                    </hgroup>

                    <?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
                    <a id="header-image" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
                        <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="" />
                    </a>
                    <?php endif; // if ( get_header_image() ) ?>

                    <nav id="access" role="navigation">
                        <h3 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Main menu', 'the-bootstrap' ); ?></h3>
                        <div class="skip-link"><a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to primary content', 'the-bootstrap' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to primary content', 'the-bootstrap' ); ?></a></div>
                        <div class="skip-link"><a class="assistive-text" href="#secondary" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to secondary content', 'the-bootstrap' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to secondary content', 'the-bootstrap' ); ?></a></div>
                        <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) OR the_bootstrap_options()->navbar_site_name OR the_bootstrap_options()->navbar_searchform ) : ?>
                        <div <?php the_bootstrap_navbar_class(); ?>>
                            <div class="navbar-inner">
                                <div class="container">
                                    <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
                                    <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    </a>
                                    <?php if ( the_bootstrap_options()->navbar_site_name ) : ?>
                                    <span class="brand"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></span>
                                    <?php endif;?>
                                    <div class="nav-collapse">
                                        <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                                            'theme_location'    =>  'primary',
                                            'menu_class'        =>  'nav',
                                            'depth'             =>  3,
                                            'fallback_cb'       =>  false,
                                            'walker'            =>  new The_Bootstrap_Nav_Walker,
                                        ) ); 
                                         ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </nav><!-- #access -->
                    <?php if ( function_exists( 'yoast_breadcrumb' ) ) {
                        yoast_breadcrumb( '<nav id="breadcrumb" class="breadcrumb">', '</nav>' );
                    }
                    tha_header_bottom(); ?>
                </header><!-- #branding --><?php
                tha_header_after();


/* End of file header.php */
/* Location: ./wp-content/themes/the-bootstrap/header.php */
```

Comment: anybody there to help plzzz help me guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In functions.php You need to include js and css files of jQuery plugin:

```
wp_enqueue_style ('your_plugin_css_handler_name', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/css/jquery-plugin-css-file.css', '', '1.0');
wp_enqueue_script( 'your_plugin_js_handler_name', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/jquery-plugin-js-file.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', false );
```

Change lines above, so they work with your plugin.

Now You need to add to header.php code that will change into carousel, and add additional .js file that will callout plugin for elements.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'theme_js', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/theme.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', false );
```

Put plugin callout in theme.js file and all should work.

for jquery cycle code looks like this:
functions.php

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'cycle_js', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/jquery.cycle.all.js', array('jquery'), '2.9', false );
wp_enqueue_script( 'theme_js', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/theme.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', false );
```

and theme.js:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#headerrotator').cycle();
})
```

#headerrotator is an element holding elements to cycle them through.